# PHP portion of code doesn't run. LAMP. RPi

Tags: php, apache, raspberry-pi, apache2, lamp

I created a webpage recently on my PC and ran it on a WAMP server where it worked perfectly and then I moved it to apache2+PHP5 server on my RPi. The webpages work except for the PHP portion of my code on my PHP page. Here's the basics of my code:

```
<html>
 <?php
 if (isset($_GET['id'] == 0){
   echo "ERROR";
  }
 else{
   echo "Please select a drink.";
  }
 ?>
 </html>
```

My intention was for my php page to read the number on the link of the html page from which the link to the php page was clicked and then show a message based on the number. The portion of the code that I have within the html bounds work perfectly but the section with the php doesn't run.

My concern is if this is an issue caused by how php is running on the RPi or if its my code. I have read blogs where people are having issues with php pages being downloaded instead of running. I personally had this issue a while back but after I fiddled with a bunch of solutions online, the page didn't download anymore and started to display the html within my php page.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Please let me know if you need further information of anything related to my issue. Thanks.

Comment: Are you seeing the PHP when you do `View Source`?

Comment: Take a look in /var/log/apache2/error and tell us if you see any helpful information in there.

Comment: ```if (isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] == 0) { echo 'ERROR'; }```

Answer (score 0):

First, check that PHP is installed (I know you've said it is, but just check). You can do this by running the following from the command line:

```
php -v
```

If that shows you have php installed, great! Move on to the next troubleshooting step.

From the issue that you have described, it sounds like apache isn't talking to PHP. You should try to install the following mod to apache. This is done via:

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5
```

Let that run and install. It will ask if you want to install the new packages, select yes. Once that is installed, go ahead and restart the apache service.

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Now, try your web page again. It should be working as you expect it to.

However, if it does still not work, change the permissions to (Read, Write, Execute - For everyone). This can be done via:

```
sudo chmod 777 name-of-your-file
```

WARNING - Don't chmod 777 on a production server, it is not secure as anyone can read/write and execute the file.

Hope that this helps, if you were unable to resolve the issue, leave a comment and I will get back to you.